# Android robotium number of runs

Tags: android, robotium

I am working with Robotuim for Android. Does anyone knows how to set a number of runs of the concrete test case?

Comment: can you please explain your question a little bit further? what are you looking for? do you want to execute a test-case automatically repeatedly? what is your intention doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following line above your test case definition:

```
@FlakyTest(tolerance=3)
```

And your test will be run 3 times

Comment: How did you get this information ? i can't find any information about Ropotium Full documentaion